# how raft achieve strong consistency when they don't require fsync on every write

Tags: distributed-system, raft

I understand the basic raft protocol and how it achieve strong consistency. However in my opinion, to achieve real consistency, you need to use fsync on every write (not only on leader but also on followers), since if you don't do that, even if you thought you are in the safe zone by a majority "committed", these logs can potentially lost in the future since they are still in the page cache.

But use fsync on every write will degrade the performance of system by orders of magnitude.

So i am wondering how do they solve the trade-off or explain to me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: Your understanding is correct, and a lot of database work is in efficiently batching writes to minimize IO overhead.

Answer (score 0):

The chance of all servers going down at the same time is less. Also, as soon as the leader fails or the term changes, one of the followers that have the most up-to-date log entries will get elected and it will commit it's entries and thus committing all entries of previous terms as well. Thus the risk is minimized.